# Is there a way to copy the symbol in TeX.SE in my book header?

Tags: header-footer, fourier

I am referring to the one right below TEX :

[image]

MWE :

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\usepackage[paperwidth=142mm, paperheight=210mm,top=25mm, bottom=20mm, left=17mm, right=22mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{fourier-orns}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\renewcommand\headrule{\hrulefill
\raisebox{-2.1pt}[10pt][10pt]{\quad\decofourleft\decotwo\decofourright\quad}\hrulefill}
\setlength{\headheight}{24.7pt}

\begin{document}

Some text.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can download an image of the ornament from https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/tex/img/sprites-extra.svg?v=f1f65415ba47

I used Inkscape to clean up the surrounding lines and convert it to .pdf, then it can simply be included as an image:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\usepackage[paperwidth=142mm, paperheight=210mm,top=25mm, bottom=20mm, left=17mm, right=22mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{fourier-orns}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\renewcommand\headrule{\hrulefill
\raisebox{-7pt}[10pt][10pt]{\quad\includegraphics[width=1cm]{sprites-extra}\quad}\hrulefill}
\setlength{\headheight}{24.7pt}

\begin{document}

Some text.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you send me the pdf image :) It's a lot of work to get it right, maybe I will get to it.